# Spring. How does Spring manage Controllers

Tags: java, spring, api, controller

I am developing an API using spring and I have some doubts.
Imagine I have a `@Controller` which one of it's endpoints takes 2 minutes to process a response.
If I do multiple petitions with different users at the same time to that specific endpoint.

How does Spring manage it? Is it concurrent?

In theory the controllers are Singleton, therefore the controller wouldn't be able to answer the next petition before he ends the last one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controllers are Singleton for sure, but they can be accessed concurrently. So many user requests can be handled in parallel by the same controller. That is why your controller should be stateless, that is, you should not store user data in the controller attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't get it. If it is a singleton and everyone uses the same object. How can the object manage multiple requests at the same time? I don't understand this

Comment: Exactly - you can always make concurrent calls to one and the same object. Why not? Your webserver takes care of initializing request threads and managing a thread pool for those request executions. The major question with this: Is your singleton "thread-safe"? And that's totally up to you. Store request-related state in your singleton, and you won't and you will get random errors as soon as you receive concurrent requests. Dont store request-related state and you are fine - your singleton would be "thread-safe" which means "safe to use in multi-threaded environments".

Comment: I mean, I can understand that you can modify an object, add information or extract it concurrently. But I cannot understand HOW you can make an object execute the same function concurrently.